# How do I assign different audio sources to different outputs?

Tags: audio, wireless-networking, headphones

XP Pro
Thinkpad t60

I have recently started using voip and for that purpose I bought a cordless headphone/mic. It works very well, but when I have it on, **all** audio goes through the headphone.

I would like to have all other audio except the phone service just come through the speakers or out of the wired headphone jack.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I invoke it?
Thanks.

Comment: what kind of cordless?  does it use a USB dongle you plug into the computer first, or is it bluetooth (and connecting via a built-in bluetooth module on your system)?

Comment: Its a usb dongle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be more or less up to your soundcard, and if your soundcard had drivers and software to support this.

Comment: seeing as how this is a laptop, maybe the laptop supplier may have a control panel that can also do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check your sound-card drivers and make sure they are up to date. If necessary, look for drivers by the manufacturer rather than the default XP drivers, as they may be more sophisticated.

Then
check to see if you have an audio control panel (in Control Panel) and
there might be an option in there as to what to do with your speaker
sound when you plug earphones in.

Also, if you use Skype, then you can configure it to use the headset specifically.